# How do I create a Draggable without using DragTarget in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, draggable

I'm a newbie at Flutter. I'm trying to create a Draggable but I don't want to use a DragTarget. I want it to drag and drop wherever I want. When I did that after the drop operation object disappeared. I don't want it to disappear. How can I do that? I checked the resources and YouTube, however, I cannot find anything useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your case draggable will only be used to get the position info, when dropped it will disappear, but you have its position. Then redraw the same object at the previous dragged position within a `Stack` for example.

Comment: But how will I do that? Can you show an example?

Comment: Did you try out the example I provided ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up to my comment, here is a code example.
You have a `Stack`, with your `Draggable` element, you then rebuild it to the new position using a `Positioned` widget and an offset.
You could also recreate a `DragTarget` following the same exemple, just repositioning it if you need its features.

You might need to adapt a bit the offset in order to make it react to your target element size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _started = false;
  Offset _position = Offset(20, 20);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: _position.dy - 30, // Size of widget to reposition correctly
              left: _position.dx,
              child: Draggable(
                child: Chip(label: Text('Element')),
                feedback: Material(
                    child: Chip(
                  label: Text('Element'),
                )),
                onDragEnd: (details) {
                  print(details.offset);
                  setState(() {
                    if (!_started) _started = true;
                    _position = details.offset;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! It worked for me. But If anyone wants to use that code, one must wrap Scaffold in a MaterialApp widget.

Comment: Indeed the base of the app is a MaterialApp for me. Thanks for your reply, do not forget to set it as Answered if it helped you :)